# Sort a table based on one condition and the list remaining rows accordingly

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I had a table with following  details

```
cID sID Name    pID childrenCount
1   1   Site    1   5    
2   1   Safty   2   4    
3   1   Archit  3   3  
4   1   Civil   1   0  
5   1   Concs   1   0  
6   1   Pavm    1   0  
7   1   Paint   3   0  
8   1   Alum    3   0  
9   1   Doors   3   0  
10  1   Highw   1   0  
11  1   Road    1   0  
12  1   Alarm   2   0  
13  1   Safty   2   0  
14  1   Fence   2   0  
15  1   Beaco   2   0
```

What I want is to write a select query to order the above table first by their childrenCount   values in descending order and the list the corresponding rows according as below

```
cID sID Name    pid childrenCount
1   1   Site    1   5  
4   1   Civil   1   0  
5   1   Conc    1   0  
6   1   Pavm    1   0  
10  1   Highw   1   0  
11  1   Road    1   0  
2   1   Safty   2   4  
12  1   Alarm   2   0   
13  1   Safty   2   0  
14  1   Fence   2   0  
15  1   Beacon  2   0  
3   1   A WRK   3   3  
7   1   Paint   3   0  
8   1   Alumin  3   0  
9   1   Doors   3   0
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: you mean something like `order by childrenCount desc`?

Comment: No..not simply order by childrenCount,but first entry be the row with highest children count,then list all the children ie,pid correspoding to first entry...main consideration on childrencount and pid field

Comment: you can list any number of columns in `order by`, the order of these columns will be the order of sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...first order by `pid` then childrenCount desc.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME order by pid, childrenCount desc
```

Comment: But I need a little more different answer
that is,
suppose if cid=2 has childrenCount 10, then too it remains in the same place,using the above query.
currently the method of working  is first order by pid then showing highest Childrencount first. But actually I need is showing the highest childrncount as first row then its corresponding children(all the other entries with the pid same as the highest childrencount and so on....)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY pid, childrenCount DESC, cid
```